# Debug developer console inserted javascript

Tags: javascript, web-console

Is there some way to debug code that you have inserted from the firefox developer console terminal? I.e I inserted

```
document.onkeydown = function(event) { 
  // check keys pressed and perform some logic 
}
```

If I knew where the javascript entered from the developer console goes(which .js file it was in) I could debug it but I haven't been able to figure that out.

Comment: cam't you just add it in code?  I'm not sure you _can_ break on inserted code.  would be awesome if you could

Comment: Put a `debugger` statement inside, this way you’ll be able to get to see your code in VM and place a breakpoint

Comment: Akxe, that was the answer I gave to my own question before it got deleted while my power was out. Oh well problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

In the chrome debug console, type this:

```
document.onkeydown = function(event) { 
  console.log(event)
}
```

The return value will be a function, like this:

[image: Chrome Debug console]

Double click on the function and a `VM.js` tab will open. This contains the code generated by the VM for this function. You can set a breakpoint there.

Answer (score 0):

The debugger; statement is exactly what I needed.

```
document.onkeydown= function(event){
    debugger;
    //function logic here
}
```

Then from the image below you can see that you can set your breakpoints in the debugger where you need them.
[image: firefox debugger snip]